# Reduce clicks when switching over cd4066

Tags: audio, switching

I make an audio switch on the chip cd4066 (I control using arduino), please tell me how to make a smoother switch without sharp clicks, I need the sound to appear with a small attack and just fade out, it should be minimal but help get rid of clicks , ideally it would be great if the duration of attack and damping could be adjusted. How to implement this schematically? I will be happy with any help.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you show an oscillogram or simulation of the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Many thanks! I'm still just starting to learn Easy Eda so I have not figured out how to make a good simulation so I tried to draw my problem. I want to do something similar to https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8Szp98UlIf8 but do all the logic on arduino. Therefore, I had a standard problem when there is a cutout not at 0 dB there are clicks, as I realized in professional versions it was solved by introducing a smooth attack and sound attenuation when cutting with a crossfader, but I do not know how to implement it schematically. http://www.dropbox.com/s/190ruzgg3gh4hmg/crossgraph01.png?dl=0

Comment: The  CD4066 switches are either on or off. There is no possibility of fading in and out with them.

Comment: I understand this, but is it possible to do this by adding new elements to the scheme?

Comment: On this page https://neatcircuits.com/audiosw/index.html there is a scheme of smooth attenuation of audio, but I do not know how to remake it to fit my needs. Probably need to reduce the capacity between 1 and sw?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you switch on channels, you are sending DC current through the switch to your outputs. The bias voltage is not needed if you use a bipolar supply of +/- 7.5 volts (maximum). Then you can remove R1, R3, R5 and R7. The ground pin of the CD4066 (Vss) will now have -7 volt. R2, R4, R6, R8 become your ground reference for the signal.

The CD4066 will work with +/- 5 volts but the allowed signal intensity will be reduced.

Since it no longer has any DC voltage on the signal lines, there should be no clicking noise when changing inputs.

To get +/- 7.5 volts use LM7808(+8 volts) and LM7908(-8 volts) voltage regulators with a 1N4007 diode on the output to drop the voltage to a safe +/- 7.35 volts. Don't forget to add bypass capacitors on the Vcc and Vss pins to ground.

Comment: Thank you, I am feeding power from arduino it is unipolar and I made a voltage divider like this https://youtu.be/-5JOKztteVU?t=4m4s at the input otherwise the signal at disconnection was not disappearing but was heard quieter in a distorted version, now everything works but I want to smooth them, I described the problem in more detail in the previous comment.